# replace Na in dataframe with value from a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
          movieName    id  Year
            birdman  1987  2010
  avengers: endgame    Na  2020
           deadpool    Na  2012
      The bird King  1230  2018
            Bla bla    Na  2013
          Lion King    Na  2020
```

and i have a list :

```
correct_id = [4563,3452,6547,9384]
```

I want to replace the value **Na** with value from **the list above** in order to get:

```
           movieName    id  Year
            birdman  1987  2010
  avengers: endgame  4563  2020
           deadpool  3452  2012
      The bird King  1230  2018
            Bla bla  6547  2013
          Lion King  9384  2020
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `loc` to get the locations where `id` column equals to `"Na"` and put your list in there:

```
df.loc[df.id.eq("Na"), "id"] = correct_id
```

If you want them integers at the end, you can use `astype`:

```
df.id = df.id.astype(int)
```

to get

```
>>> df

           movieName    id  Year
0            birdman  1987  2010
1  avengers: endgame  4563  2020
2           deadpool  3452  2012
3      The bird King  1230  2018
4            Bla bla  6547  2013
5          Lion King  9384  2020
```